Adding gaps between specific bars on a ggplot bar plot?
library(ggplot2)
library(microeco)
library(phyloseq)

# FAPROTAX differential test
# Define the custom color palette
custom_palette2 <- c(
  # Grey Category (Dark to Light)
  "#333333", # Dark Grey
  "#666666", # Medium Grey
  "#999999", # Light Grey
  
  # Light Blue Category (Dark to Light)
  "#4C8CFF", # Darker Light Blue
  "#66A3FF", # Medium Light Blue
  "#99CCFF", # Lighter Light Blue
  
 # Dark Blue Category (Further Spread: Dark to Light)
  "#001F3F", # Very Dark Blue (further adjusted)
  "#004080", # Dark Blue (further adjusted)
  "#0066CC", # Medium Dark Blue (further adjusted)
  
  # Red Category (Dark to Light)
  "#A50F15", # Dark Red
  "#DE2D26", # Medium Dark Red
  "#FB6A4A"  # Light Red
)

# Convert phyloseq object to Meco format
meco_2 <- phyloseq2meco(pseq_filtered2)
meco_2

# Functional potential analysis
t2d <- trans_func$new(meco_2)
t2d$cal_spe_func(prok_database = "FAPROTAX")
t2d$cal_spe_func_perc(abundance_weighted = TRUE)

# use list to prepare data
tmp2 <- list()

# transpose res_spe_func_perc to be a data.frame like taxonomic abundance
tmp2$func <- as.data.frame(t(t2d$res_spe_func_perc), check.names = FALSE)


# Isolate certain functions (fermentation)
func_df2 <- tmp2[["func"]]
subset_df2 <- func_df2["fermentation", ]

filt_list2 <- split(subset_df2, seq(nrow(subset_df2)))

# assign the list as taxa_abund in microtable object
meco_2$taxa_abund <- filt_list2

# use trans_diff class to perform differential test
t2a_filt <- trans_diff$new(dataset = meco_2, method = "anova", group = "sampletype", taxa_level = "all")

custom_order <- c(
  "b2na0", "b2na20", "b2na40",
  "b2nit0", "b2nit20", "b2nit40",
  "b2amm0", "b2amm20", "b2amm40",
  "b2p0", "b2p20", "b2p40")

# Set the group_order attribute of your object
t2a_filt$group_order <- custom_order

# create plot
t2a_filt$plot_diff_abund(add_sig = TRUE, color_values = custom_palette2) +
  ggplot2::ylab("Relative abundance (%)")

Hello, I have the above code which performs a functional analysis of microbial community data inferred from 16S rRNA gene sequencing results. It utilizes the FAPROTAX database to identify microbial functional potentials and then visualizes and statistically analyzes the data. I'm looking to add a gap in between certain bars - gap between b2na40 and b2nit0, gap between b2nit40 and b2amm0, and a gap between b2amm40 and b2p0...
I've tried adding blank spaces (" ") to the custom_order list, between the desired groups, though this hasn't worked. Also have tried messing with the position_dodge function and scale_x_discrete, but something isn't quite right. Still new to coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Consider making your example reproducible with the inclusion of data (e.g. via dput) and by noting which libraries you're using.

It looks like plot_diff_abund is from a package other than ggplot2, and so will probably not support the same level of customization as making the plot with ggplot2. If you can construct the plot with ggplot2 directly, you can specify the x coordinate of each bar as a column in the data, and space them out however you want.

@qdread yes, the plot_diff_abund is from the microeco package. I'm not quite sure how to plot with ggplot2 directly, I'm thinking there's got to be something to add on to 't2a_filt$plot_diff_abund(add_sig = TRUE, color_values = custom_palette2) +
ggplot2::ylab("Relative abundance (%)")' to customize gaps between bars somehow?
